# How many people has at least three color balls in their pocket

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$50$ people in total, $30$ of them have a red ball, $36$ of them have a yellow ball, $44$ of them have a blue ball. **Question: at least how many people has three balls?**

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Would you be able to do it if there were only two colors (say, if we throw away all the blue balls and asked only how many must have both a red and a yellow ball)?

Comment: @Arthur two is ok, three has problem...

Comment: from the 36 and the 44 - you can distribute them so that the least that has 2 is 30 - then if you distribute the remaining 30, only 10 have to have 3 balls.  It seems to be 10 to me

Comment: You do two colours first. Then whoever has both colours, you pretend those are a single color. Say whoever has both and yellow are called orange. Now do the same thing for orange and blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of people having a red ball, $B$ the set of people having a yellow ball and $C$ the set of people having a blue ball. Then we're after $\mid A \cap B \cap C \mid$. This is a classic [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) question. Using this we have:

$$\mid \;A \cap B \cap C \mid \; = \; \mid A \cup B \cup C \mid - \mid A \mid - \mid B \mid - \mid C \mid + \mid A \cap B \mid + \mid B \cap C \mid + \mid C \cap A \;\mid$$

Now use the Pigeonhole Principle to find the minimum values of $\mid \; A \cap B \mid, \mid B \cap C \mid, \mid C \cap A \; \mid$

Comment: |... | means the number of elements?

Comment: @fizis Yeah, the cardinality of the set.